# Linq version of SQL query with multiple joins and group bys

Tags: sql, performance, linq, entity-framework

In an attempt to write this query from a legacy database in linq, I am running into performance issues.  Is there a better way to write the below sql query in linq.

The sql query takes less than 2 seconds to run, whereas the current linq expression takes over 6 seconds.

This is from a SQL 2008R2 DB.

Here is the sql query

```sql
SELECT  People.ID,
        A.GameKey, 
        ClubCode, 
        case
            WHEN ClubCode = Home_TM_CD then Visit_TM_CD
            WHEN ClubCode = Visit_TM_CD then Home_TM_CD
        end as Opponent,            
        count(case when (ClubCode <> PossessionTeam and STPlayType = 0)  then 'super' end) as super_plays,
        (SELECT count(PlayID) 
         FROM   PLAY_LIST B 
         WHERE  A.GameKey = B.GameKey
         AND    ClubCode <> PossessionTeam 
         AND    PossessionTeam <> ''
         AND    STPlayType = 0 
         GROUP BY A.GameKey, A.ClubCode) as Total_Super_Play,
        count(case when (ClubCode = PossessionTeam and STPlayType = 0) then 'plays' end) as plays,
        (SELECT count(PlayID) 
         FROM   PLAY_LIST B 
         WHERE  A.GameKey = B.GameKey
         AND    ClubCode = PossessionTeam 
         AND    STPlayType = 0 
         GROUP BY A.GameKey, A.ClubCode) as Total_Play,         
        Season,
        Season_Type,
        Week,
        Game_DT
    FROM    PEOPLE
    INNER JOIN PEOPLE_PARTICIPATION A ON People.ID = A.ID
    inner join GAME on GameKey  = gamekey
    inner join PLAY_LIST on PLAY_LIST.GameKey = A.GameKey AND PLAY_LIST.PlayID = A.PlayID
    WHERE   Season = 2011       
    and     People.ID = 1
    group by    People.ID,
                Season,
                Season_Type,
                Week,
                Game_DT,
                A.GameKey,
                ClubCode,
                Home_TM_CD, 
                Visit_TM_CD
    order by Season, 
             CASE WHEN Season_Type = 'Reg' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, week, People.ID
```

Here is the linq expression I have so far

```cs
IQueryable<ProViewModel> playerList = (from people in db.PEOPLE
join participation in db.PARTICIPATION on people.ID equals participation.ID
join game in db.GAME on participation.GameKey equals game.Gamekey    
join playlist in db.PLAY_LIST on new { gamekey = participation.GameKey, playID = participation.PlayID } equals new { gamekey = playlist.GameKey, playID = playlist.PlayID }                                                                                    
where people.ID == 1 &&
game.Season == 2011
group playlist by new PeopleParticipationGroup{
   ID = people.ID,
   SEASON = game.Season,
   SEASON_TYPE = game.Season_Type,
   WEEK = game.Week,
   GAME_DT = game.Game_DT,
   GameKey = participation.GameKey,
   ClubCode = participation.ClubCode,
   HOME_TM_CD = game.Home_TM_CD,
   VISIT_TM_CD = game.Visit_TM_CD
} into groupedPeople
orderby groupedPeople.Key.SEASON                                                  
select new PeopleViewModel 
{   
   ID = groupedPeople.Key.ID,
   SEASON_TYPE = groupedPeople.Key.SEASON_TYPE,
   WEEK = groupedPeople.Key.WEEK,
   SEASON_TYPE_SORT = 
   (
    groupedPeople.Key.SEASON_TYPE == "REG" ? 1 :
    groupedPeople.Key.SEASON_TYPE == "POST" ? 2 : 3
   ),
   GAME_DT = groupedPeople.Key.GAME_DT,
   SEASON = groupedPeople.Key.SEASON,
   GameKey = groupedPeople.Key.GameKey,
   ClubCode = groupedPeople.Key.ClubCode,
   Opponent = 
   (
    groupedPeople.Key.ClubCode == groupedPeople.Key.HOME_TM_CD ? groupedPeople.Key.VISIT_TM_CD : groupedPeople.Key.HOME_TM_CD
   ),
   HOME_TM_CD = groupedPeople.Key.HOME_TM_CD,
   VISIT_TM_CD = groupedPeople.Key.VISIT_TM_CD,                                                       
   PLAYS = (from t in groupedPeople
                      where t.PossessionTeam == groupedPeople.Key.ClubCode && 
                      t.STPlayType == 0
                      select t).Count(),                                                       
   TOTAL_PLAYS = (from p in db.PLAY_LIST
                            where p.GameKey == groupedPeople.Key.GameKey && 
                            p.PossessionTeam == groupedPeople.Key.ClubCode && 
                            p.PossessionTeam != "" &&                                                                                 
                            p.STPlayType == 0
                            select p).Count(),
   SUPER_PLAYS = (from t in groupedPeople
                      where t.PossessionTeam != groupedPeople.Key.ClubCode && 
                      t.STPlayType == 0
                      select t).Count(),
   TOTAL_SUPER_PLAYS = (from p in db.PLAY_LIST
                            where p.GameKey == groupedPeople.Key.GameKey &&
                            p.PossessionTeam == groupedPeople.Key.ClubCode &&
                            p.PossessionTeam == "" &&
                            p.STPlayType == 0
                            select p).Count(),                                                       
}); ;
```

Comment: **UPDATE**                                                            the performance hit seems to be with the 2 columns "PLAYS" and "SUPERPLAYS". If i just set them to a constant value, the query runs on par with the sql query. Once those columns are added back the query turns slow again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how the queries are compiled, and how much optimisation is done. If it works as I expect and converts the query in the order it's defined into linq function calls, then rearranging the order could help.

For example, you could remove

```
where people.ID == 1 &&
game.Season == 2011
```

and replacing `db.PEOPLE` with `db.PEOPLE.where(p => p.id == 1)` and a similar replacement for `db.GAME`.

This would avoid the work of joining results that will later be discarded. As you have these constants it might be worth taking them out of the grouping and straight into the select.

On the other hand assuming this is LINQ to SQL, then the above probably won't help and you can use [db.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx) to see what the query is translated to in SQL. Then you can rearrange until your LINQ matches or improves on the original SQL.

Comment: I am using EF 4.0, so there is no db.log.  I also tried moving the where like you suggested, but that made no difference.